# AlertDialog: How To Remove Black Borders Above and Below View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

This question has been asked before: [AlertDialog custom title has black border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222241/alertdialog-custom-title-has-black-border)

But was not answered satisfactorily - and is missing some information.

---

I'm trying to create a custom dialog in Android without a title and without any buttons along the bottom.

However, the resulting dialog has black "borders"/"spacing"/something along the top and bottom of the view.

From [the Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog):

> A dialog made with the base Dialog class must have a title. If you
>   don't call setTitle(), then the space used for the title remains
>   empty, but still visible. If you don't want a title at all, then you
>   should create your custom dialog using the AlertDialog class. However,
>   because an AlertDialog is created easiest with the AlertDialog.Builder
>   class, you do not have access to the setContentView(int) method used
>   above. Instead, you must use setView(View). This method accepts a View
>   object, so you need to inflate the layout's root View object from XML.

So, that's what I did:

**Welcome.java**

```
public class Welcome  extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcomedialog, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

**welcomedialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/texturebg"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="40px">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE:** I've tried using `FrameLayout` as the root `ViewGroup` instead of `LinearLayout` as per a suggestion I found somewhere - but that didn't help.

**Result**

[image]
[image]

---

### setBackgroundDrawable Suggestion

```
public class Welcome  extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcomedialog, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(layout);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Didn't work for me.

Comment: Can this code use setPositiveButton method? If I the new view I made in layout has buttons, how to set onClickListener callback?

Comment: @Fakebear, I think your comment/question is outside the scope of this question. You'll probably want to search for that and/or start a new question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you look at the [AlertDialog class source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/AlertDialog.java) you'll see most of the methods are simply proxy methods (facade) around `private AlertController mAlert`.

Looking at the [AlertController class source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java#AlertController) you'll see 4 interesting member variables:

```
private int mViewSpacingLeft;
private int mViewSpacingTop;
private int mViewSpacingRight;
private int mViewSpacingBottom;
private boolean mViewSpacingSpecified = false;
```

Setting `mViewSpacingSpecified` to `true` will remove the borders on the top and bottom of the dialog.

This is done properly by changing this line:

```
dialog.setView(layout);
```

to:

```
dialog.setView(layout, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Worked for me with this small edit, thanks!  

`AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();`  
`dialog.setView(layout,0,0,0,0);`  
`dialog.show();`

Comment: @Steve a big THANK YOU! After hours of research, dealing with custom theming and styling I finally found your answer which solved my problem!

Comment: Some small border still stays here, but better.

Comment: @Steve many thanks i have been fighting with this issue for hours... :)

Comment: it showing this error "The method setView(int) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (View, int, 
 int, int, int)"

Comment: He is not aplying it to the builder, he is aplying it to the dialog itself

Answer (score 8):

```
dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
```

use the above in your code to remove the border of the alert dialog.

Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setInverseBackgroundForced(boolean)) for InverseBackgroundForced.

**UPDATED** Try this code::::

```
public class Welcome  extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Welcome.this);
        LayoutInflater _inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Welcome.this);
        View view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcomedialog,null);
        builder.setView(view);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

**Note::** Also try by removing android:padding="40px" from welcomedialog.xml.

Comment: This changed the black to white - but still leaves the space.

Comment: False makes the background black - but still leaves the space.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, that border was caused by the theme of the parent Activity for the AlertDialog. To get rid of the border completely, give it a different theme (in this case, Holo):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo)
                              );
```

This fixed it for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, using a custom DialogFragment

Answer (score 1):

Just to make Steve's answer more clear, this can be done easily. For example in my case the view I was setting in the dialog was a WebView.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());
    webView.loadUrl(" url to show ");


    OnClickListener clickListenerOk = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ...
        }
    };

    OnClickListener clickListenerCancel = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ...
        }
    };

    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())

            .setPositiveButton("OK", clickListenerOk)

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",clickListenerCancel)

            .create();

    dialog.setView(webView, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Call this in your dialog.

Comment: On the dialog's window or view?